# Snap.svg: how to make scaled group stays in place?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have a simple SVG file like this :

```
<svg id="mySVG" /*other attributes"*/>      
  <group id="mixUps">
    <ellipse /*ellipse atributtes  blabla*/ />
    <path /*this is a star-shaped path*/ />
    <rect /*rect attributes*/ />
  /* 
   Basically this is just a simple SVG group containing an ellipse, a path and a rectangle
  */
  </g>
</svg>
```

and then, in the script file, I want this group to be scaled twice it's original size at mouseover event, and return to it's original size at mouseout :

```
<script>
var mySvg = Snap("#mySvg");
var mixUps = mySvg.select("#mixUps");

function mixCursor(evt){
  if(evt.type==="mouseover"){
      mixUps.animate({transform:"s2"}, 250);
  }else if(evt.type==="mouseout"){
        mixUps.animate({transform:"s1"}, 250);
  }
}

mixUps.mouseover(mixCursor);
mixUps.mouseout(mixCursor);
</script>
```

However, at the first mouseover event, the group somehow translated (moved) to upper-left corner, and stays there, why is this? How to make this group stays in place when scaled?

I put the file [here](http://www.pristineparadise.com/practices/tesGroupTransform.svg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the initial transform that's in place, otherwise it will get overwritten, so you want original transform THEN new transform, so instead of

```
mixUps.animate({transform: 's2'}, 250);
```

use

```
mixUps.animate({transform: this.transform() + 's2'}, 250);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfwgxqs2/6/)

Or better is to store the original transform, so we can revert back to it later...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfwgxqs2/4/)

```
mixUps.data('originalTransform', mixUps.transform() )
...
mixUps.animate({transform: this.data('originalTransform') + 's2'}, 250);
...
mixUps.animate({transform: this.data('originalTransform') }, 250);
```

Comment: nice @Ian thanks, I would like to add a tiny bit of correction : in your latest jsfiddle, you have this line :       var bb = mixUps.getBBox();in the event handler function, if we have that line, the group will behave a little strange at the very first mouseover event (I tested on ofline Opera and Firefox). Just delete that line, and everything will work fine.

Comment: I have updated the fiddles as they weren't needed, just a bit of old code. I'm not sure why that would affect anything though (it didn't in Chrome).